# Loading Html With React Native Webview

Tags: react-native, jsx

So I've been trying to load an HTML page in a Webview in React Native but haven't been able to do this, can't seeem to figure out what I'm getting wrong.

The Webview displays the form, but keeps on loading endlessly(I'm using onLoadStart and onLoadEnd to monitor when the Webview is loading), and when I click on the button in the form nothing happens, I just get a certain error in the console that says. `http load failed error code -999`.

Here is the html I've been trying to load:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="position: relative; float: left; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            .button{
                border: none;
                display: inline-block;
                background-color:#603a7e;
                color: #ffffff;
                padding: 15px 20px;
                border-radius: 6px;
                font-weight: 900;
            }
            .button:focus{
                background-color:#724695;
                color: #ffffff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="position: relative; float: left; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; padding: 0px 0px; margin: 0px 0px;">
        <form action="http://payment-url.com" method="POST" style="text-align: center; position: relative; float: left; width: 100%; height: initial;">
            <input type="hidden" name="names" value="John Doe" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100000" />
            <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="mail@jd.co" />
            <input type="hidden" name="phone_number" value="080XXXXXXXX" />
            <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="NGN" />
            <input type="hidden" name="merch_txnref" value="XXXXXXXXX" />
            <input type="hidden" name="merchantid" value="XXXXXXX" />
            <button type="submit" class="button">Make Payment Now</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my Webview implementation:

```
<WebView source={{html: this.state.source}} style={[Styles.misc.spanned]}
    javaScriptEnabled={true} initialScale={100}
    onLoadStart={this._loadStart.bind(this)} onLoadEnd={this._loadEnd.bind(this)}/>
```

Any idea what I could possibly be doing wrong here? Can't seem to figure it out, thanks in advance.

NB: I've developing for iOS and Android, but testing while I'm working on iOS.

Comment: try giving a style={{flex:1}}. But yes, webview is wonky in react-native

Comment: @MukeshSoni yeah have done that, updated my question to be more clear, thing is it actually displays the form but the form isn't submitting and since i'm using onLoadStart and onLoadEnd I was able to tell that the Webview keeps loading endlessly until it timesout.